# Mysql error 1175 when the query has a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I think there should be something stupid, but I´m getting:
 `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.  0.000 sec` when running this query:

```
update cities 
set province_id = 1
where name = 'Palma de Mallorca';
```

Comment: You should do exactly what the error message says...

Comment: In mysql workbench, Preferences -> SQL Queries and disable safe mode option

Comment: 'Safe mode' avoids you to run dangerous queries, I think you can avoid this alert adding "limit 1" to the string

Comment: @MichaelWagner  I got this error sometimes when I try to run an update without a where. But what is strange for me is this time I´m running the query with a where. I shouldn´t get this error, right?

Comment: @Olvathar you are right!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to disable the safe mode option.  Just do your query and update the row **via ID instead of some other field**.  i.e.

```
update cities 
set province_id = 1
where id = 45;
```

If your mysql table does not have an ID field.  Add one, make it auto increment and set it as the primary key.  Then run your query again.

Comment: Your answer is right. However, I need to filter by name. Is there any way? Os should I disable the safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a key column with an expression you know evaluates as "true", e.g. `id > 0`, where `id` is your key column and is value is greater than 0

```
update cities 
set province_id = 1
where name = 'Palma de Mallorca'
and id > 0;
```